# Usage of That and The

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentences here which is the correct one.

1. I would like to inform you that the departure timing has been changed.
2. I would like to inform you the departure timing has changed.
3. I would like to inform you that  departure timing has changed.

And why? When should I use that and the?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, "*departure timing*" isn't the common phrase, it's "*departure time*". "*has changed*" means that it's not the same as was before, I'd recommend "*has been changed*" or "*was changed*" to stress that somebody changed it.

"**that**" is a conjunction here. It introduces a subordinate clause "*the departure timing has changed.*"

"**the**" is a definite article that makes something definite, distinct. "**Departure time**" of a certain train or aircraft should be a definite one, so "**the**" is necessary. If the departure time of all trains or airplanes was changed then "**the**" may be omitted.

Comment: When you down-vote, please, include your comment.

Comment: While I agree that comments can be helpful, downvoters are under no obligation to leave one – anonymous downvoting is a right. Also, I notice that you often dish out a lot of questionable advice in many of your answers. (There are a couple things in this answer I disagree with, but I don’t have time to delve into them here.)

Comment: @J.R. Of course, for you as a native Speaker it's not interesting to know where your mistakes are. However, I always wish to know when I'm wrong and when I am right!

Comment: I’ll say one thing – you should avoid making sweeping generalizations and declaring that anything that doesn’t fall under that umbrella must be “incorrect.” Only pedants think like that, and such lines of reasoning are a good way to attract deserving downvotes. “You can’t start a subordinate clause without a conjunction” – says who? Have a read through the answer and some of the comments [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/complex-sentence-without-a-subordinating-conjunction) for some opposing opinions from real experts.

Comment: or "time of departure"